# How to properly aggregate unique count with Apache Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I am working with a simple dataset like this:

```
Item-Sold      Date
Desk A       2/1/2014
Desk A       2/1/2014
Desk A       2/1/2014
Desk A       2/1/2014
Desk B       2/1/2014
Desk C       2/1/2014
Chair A      2/2/2014
Chair B      2/2/2014
Chair B      2/2/2014
```

I need help writing a piglatin query to find the # of unique items sold by date

So my output would be:

```
Date      Unique-Items-Sold
2/1/2014         3
2/2/2014         2
```

I am having trouble creating the right statement that would work.  Looking for some help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    --unique_count.pig
    items = LOAD 'items.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (item,date);
    grpd = GROUP items BY date;
    distinct_cnt = FOREACH grpd {
              it = items.item;
              unique_it = distinct it;
              GENERATE group, COUNT(unique_it);
    };
    DUMP distinct_cnt;
```

Hope this helps!!